# SQL Cross Apply with three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, msdn, cross-apply

I am trying to combine 3 tables using Cross Apply in a time-efficient manor. I can get the results that I want, but the run time is too great. The three tables are:

-`CUSTOMERS`, which has the columns `CustomerId`(primary key) and `CurrentSetType`

-`HISTORY`, which has the columns `CustomerId`(foreign key), `SetType`, and `TimeStamp`

-`UPDATELIST`, which has the column `CustomerId`

My goal is to find the most recent `SetType` from `HISTORY` for each `CustomerId` in `UPDATELIST` that is different from the `CurrentSetType` (this is part of a glorified 'undo' button). I believe my problem is that the `CUSTOMERS` and `HISTORY` tables are enormous, and I don't think I'm getting them paired down to the smaller `UPDATELIST` before doing a cross apply on the entire thing. My current query is this:

```
DECLARE @UPDATELIST TABLE (Identifier INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO @UPDATELIST (Identifier) VALUES (#####); -- a few hundred lines of this

SELECT CustomerId, ITEM.SetType
FROM CUSTOMERS
CROSS APPLY
 (SELECT TOP 1 SetType FROM HISTORY
  WHERE HISTORY.CustomerId IN (SELECT Identifier FROM @UPDATELIST)
  AND HISTORY.CustomerId = CUSTOMERS.CustomerId
  AND HISTORY.SetType != CUSTOMERS.CurrentSetType ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC) AS ITEM
```

What is the most efficient query for this?

EDIT:  I am using MSDN SQL version 12.0.5532

Comment: Which SQL are you using? Microsoft, MySql? What version?

Comment: What rdbms are you using? Please [edit] your question to include the relevant rdbms (product and version tag)

Comment: What is MSDN SQL???  It's SQL Server.  So add the tag to your question.  Learn to tag properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be something like this:

```
SELECT
    CustomerID
    , SetType
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            C.CustomerID
            , H.SetType
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.CustomerID ORDER BY H.TimeStamp DESC) R
        FROM
            CUSTOMERS C
            JOIN UPDATELIST U ON U.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
            JOIN HISTORY H ON
                H.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
                AND H.SetType <> C.CurrentSetType
    ) Q
WHERE R = 1
```

How does that work?

Comment: Less than a second! Using 'ROW_NUMBER()' was a great idea, it lets you skip using 'TOP' altogether